# Как получить название города на английском?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, геолокация

Нужно получить название города текущей локации на английском с помощью Geocoder (не обязательно с ним. если есть другой несложный вариант, напишите пожалуйста), но выдает на транслите. Например, нужен "Saint-Peterburg", а получаю "Sankt-Peterburg" или вместо "Moscow" выдает "Moskva"
Код:

```
val aLocale = Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").setScript("Latn").build()
        val gcd = Geocoder(requireContext(), aLocale)
        var addresses: List<Address>? = null
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(it.latitude, it.longitude, 1)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        if (addresses != null && addresses.isNotEmpty()) {
            val locality: String = addresses[0].locality
            Log.d("LOCALE", "city: $locality")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, в этом отношении царит некоторый хаос. Смотрите этот список отчетов об ошибках API геокодирования Google.

ты используешь старое V2 API.

Согласно этому сообщению и моим собственным тестам, новый V3 API:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Rome&sensor=false&language=en
```

более чувствителен к языковому параметру и правильно переводит названия населенных пунктов. Я получаю правильные результаты для language=en (Rome), language=de (Rom) и даже language=fi (Rooma)!
Тем не менее, V3 предоставляет результаты геокодирования в другом формате, поэтому вам придется значительно изменить свой синтаксический анализ (из-за того, как сейчас структурированы componentADDRESS, это тоже меня достало).